# Bizarre behavior of list

Tags: java

I have defined list from `0-9(Integer)` as below:

```
List<Integer> list = 
                IntStream.range(0, 10)
                         .boxed()
                         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

When I try to remove elements using below code:

```
list.stream()
            .peek(list::remove)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It should throw `ConcurrentModificationException` but interestingly it works for some of the elements and gives below output(threw exception at the end and removed some of the elements):

```
0
2
4
6
8
null
null
null
null
null
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

But if I have added `sorted()` like below:

```
list.stream()
            .sorted()
            .peek(list::remove)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This worked perfectly fine and removed all the elements, I am confused why `stream` behaves this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you looked at the *source code* how these classes are implemented?

The method `sorted()` will make a *copy* of your list for sorting.

It thus behaves differently: you are iterating over the sorted *copy* then, but removing from the *first* list only.

#### peek() is discouraged

The method `peek` is discouraged to use; from the JavaDoc:

> This method exists mainly to support debugging

It's okay to put a `System::println` there or similar for development purposes, but it is not a functionality you should use for your final program.

### Never attempt to modify the current stream

Read the API specification of the stream package:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference

> For most data sources, preventing interference means **ensuring that the data source is not modified at all during the execution of the stream pipeline.**

So, in other words: **you are not allowed to remove from a list that you are currently streaming**, there are no guarantees that it will work.

#### What is happening

Your initial list is

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]        pos = 0
```

You print `0` and remove it, then advance to the next position. The new array is then

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, null]     pos = 1
```

At the *next position* the value is now `2`, so print and remove `2`:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, null, null]  pos = 2
```

and so on. The problem is, that because of your concurrent removals, the remainder of the list keeps on moving forward.

The `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown at the *end of the stream*. This appears to be a performance decision (only check once for concurrent modifications, not at every iteration) for `forEachRemaining` only, so this stream is *not fail-fast*

Comment: I think you got it, when you add flavor of `.parallel()` it behaves completely different so I guess we should abstain from removing element while using `stream`, one should not be modifying backing collection.

Comment: Still doesn't answer why some elements are or are not removed, in first case.

Comment: Well, that is happening because after removing `0`, the next element is `2`. Every even element is removed, and the odd elements move up the list.